# How to add a button programmatically?

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

I try to add a Button to my RelativLayout.
It works,  but the Buttons are overlapping each other.
I guess I'm overriding the LayoutParams, or I'm using the wrong methods, but I don't know.

This is only a test. In the final version, I want to add an undefined number of Buttons to a scrollView with a relativLayout in it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    Button myButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                    myButton.setText("Push Me");

                    RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_main);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    lp.topMargin = R.id.button;
                    myButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    ll.addView(myButton);

                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

**The XML-File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.freddy.test.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/relative_main">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add new Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The buttons are overlapping each other because you are using a RelativeLayout without telling at which place is the button supposed to go relative to the Layout. 
Something that may help you would be to use a LinearLayout instead of the RelativeLayout and add the Buttons to it.

Answer (score 0):

> But this is only a test, in the Final version i want to add an
>   undefined number of buttons to a scrollview with a relativLayout in
>   it.

If your problem is that

> the Buttons are overlapping each other

It is relatively simple to solve. Use `<LinearLayout>` instead
In your  root Tag just add a attribute called `android:orientation="vertical"` or `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

There are also attributes to solve this for a RelativeLayout but it is a little more complex. 
If these are problems u have often, I suggest you take [**this**](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837) course.

example:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: In the Final version there are 4 Buttons in a row and that only works with a RelativLayout and i want  to add an undefined number of these rows

Comment: I added an example, it should work also with LinearLayout, but I am not super sure if that is what you mean.

Comment: Ok thanks man, but i already found a solution, but great work!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead of FrameLayout.LayoutParams
This gives you more control over relative layout children (since your parent layout is a RelativeLayout)

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

You can align to another view by this:
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.putyourviewhere);

This is if you stick to RelativeLayout. But the solution of LinearLayout is ok also. But RelativeLayout has more control

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a `RelativeLayout` you have to use `toRightOF` if you want the buttons to be lined **horizontally** or `below` if you want the buttons to be lined **vertically**, so to add any of them programmatically, just add it as a rule to your `layoutParams`:

```
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.button);
```

OR

```
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.button);
```

Comment: great :) so kindly accept my answer as it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


lp.topMargin = R.id.button;
// use some meaningful margin, R.id.button can return any integer value. 


// you have issue with alignment of button

ll.addView(myButton);
// with this call your button should be in view hierarchy now you have to align your button. best is use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and make your button relative(top/bottom/left/right) to some other component in viewgroup(RelativeLayout).
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, now try to ADD another parameters to control the layout like centering CENTER_HORIZONTAL

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, -1); // -1 means that CENTER_HORIZONTAL doesn't take a view as a parameter
```